# Determining the probability of 6th round championship win

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

You are betting on a tournament, teams X and Y play until first to four wins. You want to place a bet on the 6th round. What is the probability of team X winning the tournament in the 6th round?

My thinking for this question is that for X to win in the 6th round they'd have to win three and lose 2 and win round 6 as well as the half chance they win each round. Right now I believe the answer would be 5C3 x 1/2^6 for a final answer of 5/32. Is this approach correct? I was also considering a bayes theorem approach where the chance of the 6th win is a combination of smaller probailities For example P(X)+ P(Y)+P(XX) + P(XY)+ P(YX)... but it did not seem like the correct approach.

Comment: You seem to be assuming they have an equal chance of winning each round and each round is independent of the others.  If so, your ${5 \choose 3}\frac1{2^6}$ looks sensible for $X$ to win on the $6$th round.  Otherwise (still assuming independence)  ${5 \choose 3}p^4(1-p)^2$ might be appropriate.

Comment: When exactly is "now"?  Just immediately before the 6th game?  Before the first game?  "The probablility" changes as $X,Y$ play more games (assuming each game independent and $X,Y$ have same a priori probability of winning each game, etc.).